# Cypress, get the numeric value of an attribute

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing, angular-e2e, e2e

To avoid going crazy again, is it possible to get the value of the `htmlTemplate`of this element?

```
 <rect x="303" y="28" height="53" width="10" htmlTemplate="foo: 115" class="foo"></rect>
```

I would like to get the number of that `foo`, so just the number 115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to assert the value `foo: 115` then you can do this.

```js
cy.get('rect').invoke('attr', 'htmlTemplate').should('equal', 'foo: 115')
```

Now if you want to extract the number part, you can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('rect')
  .invoke('attr', 'htmlTemplate')
  .then((val) => {
    cy.log(val.split(' ')[1]) //prints 115
    expect(val.split(' ')[1]).to.equal('115')
  })
```

If you have more than one rect and you want to access the first one you can use `eq(0)`

```js
cy.get('rect').eq(0).invoke('attr', 'htmlTemplate').should('equal', 'foo: 115')
```

If you want to get the value of all the rects, you can use `each()`, something like:

```js
cy.get('rect').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele)
    .invoke('attr', 'htmlTemplate')
    .then((val) => {
      cy.log(val.split(' ')[1]) //prints value one by one
    })
})
```

Comment: if I have more than one 'rect' it takes me only the first one it finds right? if I want to take them all, can I cycle them?